# What are the best audio and video codecs to use for all major browsers?

Tags: video, audio

I'm setting up a website that will stream video and audio and I need to decide which codec to store the media in.

What is the best in terms of quality when it comes to audio and video codecs that are supported on Safari, Chrome, Edge, and Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably  h.264  (for video) and mp3 or AAC for audio.

https://caniuse.com/is a pretty good resource.  It says h.265/HEVC is not supported on Firefox and has good, but not full support in Edge.  (https://caniuse.com/?search=h.264) leaving you with h.264 which has wide browser coverage.

https://caniuse.com/?search=mp3 shows pretty full browser support (other then Opera Mini which appears to have been deprecated in 2015), and the same for AAC.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the open-source, royalty-free [AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1) video codec and [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) audio codec.

- https://caniuse.com/?search=av1
- https://caniuse.com/?search=opus

Comment: Unfortunately Edge does not support AV1.    AFAIK, Opus is good for low latency but AAC has better quality at lower bit rates making it a better fit for streaming - still. OPUS is apparently better then MP3.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful information.